# How can I make Ansible use the SSH signed client certificate for connections?

Tags: ansible, ssh-keys

I have implemented SSH CA client signing on my servers. Sshd is configured on my servers with the following directive:

`TrustedUserCAKeys /etc/ssh/trusted-users-ca.pem`

I modified my local ssh config file so my cert is sent as well, when I connect to my servers:

```
Host *.internal.headincloud.be
        User centos
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/datacenter-hic-deploy
        CertificateFile = ~/.ssh/datacenter-hic-deploy-cert.pub
```

This seems to work just fine, and I'm able to connect to my server without the need to deploy an authorized_keys file.

However, Ansible is unable to connect my servers:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [postgres-01]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "SSH Error: data could not be sent to remote host \"192.168.90.40\". Make sure this host can be reached over ssh", "unreachable": true}
```

Like I already mentioned, I'm able to connect via ssh just fine.

I suspect Ansible is not sending the certificate file along, and that's why I am unable to connect.

I tried modifying my ansible.cfg as follows:

```
ssh_args = -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -i ~/.ssh/datacenter-hic-deploy-cert.pub
```

or

```
ssh_args = -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -i /Users/jeroenjacobs/.ssh/datacenter-hic-deploy-cert.pub
```

Neither of those work.

I cannot a find a way to tell Ansible how to do this. Anyone an idea?

Comment: At first glance Ansible seems to connect to a host named `192.168.90.40` but your ssh config is set up for hosts using host  names ending in internal.headincloud.be  , not ip-addresses ; possibly you need to ensure that Ansible connects using the correct host name in the ssh connection  rather than the ip-address

Comment: Ah yes, I had a mismatch in my inventory file, and I was using ip addresses there! Fixing this to hostnames has fixed the issue. Can you put this as an answer, instead of a comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> fatal: [postgres-01]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false,
>   "msg": "SSH Error: data could not be sent to remote host \"192.168.90.40\".
>   Make sure this host can be reached over ssh", "unreachable"

At first glance Ansible seems to connect to a host named `192.168.90.40` but your ssh config is set up for hosts using host names ending in `*.internal.headincloud.be` , not ip-addresses.

Check your inventory, possibly you need to ensure that Ansible connects using the correct host name in the ssh connection rather than the ip-address, or you will need to make a second stanza in your ~/.ssh/config matching the ip-addresses you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You can make Ansible use an arbitrary private key by setting the `ansible_ssh_private_key_file` variable. The best place to set this variable depends on which servers the key needs to be used with. If it's every server, then you could do something like this:

```
$ cat group_vars/all/sshkey 
ansible_ssh_private_key_file: /Users/jeroenjacobs/.ssh/datacenter-hic-deploy
```

Comment: Please provide more info, as I don't understand why my naming convention is wrong. "datacenter-hic-deploy" is the private key, "datacenter-hic-deploy.pub" is the public key, and "datacenter-hic-deploy-cert.pub" is the ssh ca-signed certificate.

Comment: @JeroenJacobs OK, then that doesn't apply. I misread the question.